# How to prevent dplyr::select from combining names rather than assigning a new name?

Tags: r, select, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to select columns based on another named vector and assign a new name for that column at the same time. However dplyr appears to combine the names and I can't see an option to stop this in the documentation.

```
# dplyr ‘1.1.2’
# R Version 4.3.0

data <- data.frame(day = 1,
                   week = 2,
                   n_in_year = 365)

new_values <- c(period = "day",
 n = 365)

# This combines the names rather than assigning a new name
data %>%
  dplyr::select(time = new_values[1])

# e.g
#   time...period
# 1             1

# I want it to behave like this
data %>%
  dplyr::select(new_values[1]) %>%
  dplyr::rename(time = period)
```

Comment: what is your goal here, how does the final data.frame should look like? Currently with `select`, you end up with only one column from `new_values`, so you wouldn't need `data` in the first place

Comment: This reprex, is just to show the (IMO undesirable) behaviour of dplyr::select.

Comment: `data %>% select(setNames(new_values[1], "time"))`

Comment: Also, the output from `print(new_values)` may be informative: you're attempting to combine character and numeric values in the same vector.  The result may not be what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

Your issue is that `new_values` still has its `names()`:

```r
data %>% dplyr::select(time = new_values[1])
#>   time...period
#> 1             1

data %>% dplyr::select(time = unname(new_values)[1])
#>   time
#> 1    1
```

This behavior is intentional, for the ["tidy selection"](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org) used by `dplyr::select()`.  Passing a named `character` vector (like `new_values`) of column names will allow a programmatic user to ["combine" and "propagate"](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/articles/syntax.html#renaming-variables) column names in various hierarchies.  This is illustrated by the documentation below, with `symbol`s rather than strings:

> ```
> mtcars %>% select_loc(foo = c(mpg, cyl))
> #> foo1 foo2 
> #>    1    2
> ```

> ```
> mtcars %>% select_loc(foo = c(bar = mpg, baz = cyl))
> #> foo...bar foo...baz 
> #>         1         2
> ```

> ```
> mtcars %>% select_loc(foo = c(bar = c(mpg, cyl)))
> #> foo...bar1 foo...bar2 
> #>          1          2
> ```

## Solution

While `unname()` does the job, you're better off just using `[[` to extract the value without the name (`period`)...

```r
#                                       |---|
data %>% dplyr::select(time = new_values[[1]])
#>   time
#> 1    1

#                                       |----------|
data %>% dplyr::select(time = new_values[["period"]])
#>   time
#> 1    1
```

...or better yet, making `new_values` a `list`, so its values (like `365`) are not all coerced to strings (like `"365"`) in a `character` vector:

```r
# Original 'new_values' as a vector...
new_values <- c(period = "day", n = 365)
new_values
#> period      n 
#>  "day"  "365" 

# ...and new 'new_values' as a list:
new_values <- list(period = "day", n = 365)
new_values
#> $period
#> [1] "day"
#> 
#> $n
#> [1] 365


# Easily select() what you want:        |-----|
data %>% dplyr::select(time = new_values$period)
#>   time
#> 1    1
```

Comment: Thanks Greg for this clear and comprehensive answer

Answer (score 1):

Please check the updated code below

```r
# dplyr ‘1.1.2’
# R Version 4.3.0

data <- data.frame(day = 1,
                   week = 2,
                   n_in_year = 365)

new_values <- c(period = "day",
                n = 365)

# This combines the names rather than assigning a new name
data %>%
  dplyr::select(time = new_values[[1]])

  time
1    1

# I want it to behave like this
data %>%
  dplyr::select(new_values[[1]]) %>%
  dplyr::rename(time = day)
```

Comment: Thanks I agree, this works, It's actually what I implemented. But I'm still wondering why dplyr::select does this for named vectors.

Comment: @JCran  According to the [documentation here](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/articles/syntax.html#renaming-variables) for "tidy selection", this behavior is intentional: it lets programmatic users (ie. with dynamic sets of column names like `new_values`) rename columns in hierarchical fashion: `foo1` and `foo2`, or `foo...bar` and `foo...baz`, or even `foo...bar1` and `foo...bar2`.

Comment: @JCran I have [updated](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76566608/timeline#history_cf9c4a52-f40b-4f72-a732-86d48a2070ff) my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76566608) with further explanation.